# Redux form onSubmit returns empty object

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I followed the documentation at http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/GettingStarted.md/

"redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED" is triggered successfully and updated values can be seen in new state. However onSubmit returns an empty object.

Parent Component

```
handleChange(values) {
    console.log(values);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <OffCampusForm onSubmit={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Form Component

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
                </div>                    
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   auth,
   routing: routerReducer,
   profile,
   form: formReducer
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2017 is this related to you?